# Issue with an AI with Alpha-Beta pruning - Java

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, alpha-beta-pruning, iterative-deepening

I'm taking an Artificial Intelligence class where we need to create an AI that plays Tic-Tac-Toe.

The instructor specified to use alpha-beta pruning for the AI's decision making process when placing it's next move. The issue I'm running into at this point is the amount of time it takes for the AI to create the decision tree and make its move. Normal 3x3 is fine, and 3x4 and 4x3 take a little time, but 4x4 takes multiple minutes for the first move, and I haven't gotten results out of game boards larger than that.

Source code I used:

```
  /** Get next best move for computer. Return int[2] of {row, >col} */ 
  @Override 
  int[] move() {
     int[] result = minimax(2, mySeed, Integer.MIN_VALUE, >Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        // depth, max-turn, alpha, beta
     return new int[] {result[1], result[2]};   // row, col
  }

  /** Minimax (recursive) at level of depth for maximizing or >minimizing player
      with alpha-beta cut-off. Return int[3] of {score, row, col}  >*/    
  private int[] minimax(int depth, Seed player, int alpha, int >beta) {
     // Generate possible next moves in a list of int[2] of {row, >col}.
     List<int[]> nextMoves = generateMoves();

     // mySeed is maximizing; while oppSeed is minimizing
     int score;
     int bestRow = -1;
     int bestCol = -1;

     if (nextMoves.isEmpty() || depth == 0) {
        // Gameover or depth reached, evaluate score
        score = evaluate();
        return new int[] {score, bestRow, bestCol};
     } else {
        for (int[] move : nextMoves) {
           // try this move for the current "player"
           cells[move[0]][move[1]].content = player;
           if (player == mySeed) {  // mySeed (computer) is >maximizing player
              score = minimax(depth - 1, oppSeed, alpha, beta)[0];
              if (score > alpha) {
                 alpha = score;
                 bestRow = move[0];
                 bestCol = move[1];

              }
           } else {  // oppSeed is minimizing player
              score = minimax(depth - 1, mySeed, alpha, beta)[0];
              if (score < beta) {
                 beta = score;
                 bestRow = move[0];
                 bestCol = move[1];
              }
           }
           // undo move
           cells[move[0]][move[1]].content = Seed.EMPTY;
           // cut-off
           if (alpha >= beta) break;
        }
        return new int[] {(player == mySeed) ? alpha : beta, >bestRow, bestCol};
     }
 }
```

[Source link](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/javagame_tictactoe_ai.html) if it is needed

The instructor also suggested using iterative deepening search, but I am a dummy who doesn't know how.

Comment: Next time just paste your code into the editor, then choose all of it, press `ctrl-k` or the `{}` button on the toolbar and it is properly formatted. Also try to find tags that are relevant and specific to your post (alpha-beta pruning and iterative deepening both had a tag already)

Comment: From a brief look, the approach seems ok; what kind of computer did you use to measure the time? Several minutes seem extremely for for any 'modern' computer (say a PC running Windows built after 2000).

Comment: How complex is the `evaluate` function? Could you do some debugging and count in a global variable how many times it is called?